# PowerShell Script - Issue - Windows Form

Tags: powershell

Using Windows form, I've created a button that when hit, adds a user to SharePoint group. It works but  freezes up after the first time. Doesn't allow me to proceed with the script or add more than one group for the user.

Now, if I use the exact same code without Windows form, it works fine. I've tried placing the code in a separate PowerShell script and invoking it, and it does the same thing. I'm thinking there is a bug with adding users with PowerShell Windows form with SharePoint module. All my other 365 connections work fine.

Anyone able to replicate? I'm using PowerShell 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Placed the code outside the form, for it to auto run before windows form is produce and it worked fine. It appears there is an issue with the SharePoint connection and windows form. The "ADD-SPOUser" command freezes up.